# I can't seem to run the program and printf

Tags: c, printf

When I run the program the printf is not printing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int num, i=1 ;
    scanf("%c",&num);
    for(i=1; 1<num; i++);
        printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  What input are you typing into the program?  On a side note, you need to use `%i` for `int`s instead of `%c`.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to output a newline after a message: `printf("Hello World\n");` for example.

Comment: it still wouldnt print hello world with those changes

Comment: Your loop has `for(i=1; 1<num; i++);` — it should be `for (i = 1; i < num; i++) printf("Hello World\n");`.  If `num` is greater than `1`, you have an infinite loop.  You run into integer overflow eventually, but that doesn't have to crash the program — and `1` will still be less than `num`.

Comment: You should also use `int main()` if you include `return 0;` — or preferably `int main(void)`.  [Only on Windows can you use `void main(void)` legitimately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/15168), but you can't then have `return 0;` at the end.

Comment: At least gcc has a warning against misleading semicolons like this. Do yourself a favour and stop troubleshooting bugs that the compiler has already found for you, but not told you about. [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `;` after your `for` loop. It acts as an empty statement and hence your `printf` isn't inside the `for` loop.

Comment: There are [other problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70675849/i-cant-seem-to-run-the-program-and-printf#comment124941763_70675849) in the loop.

Comment: And a sneaky one at that.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int num, i=1 ;
    scanf("%c",&num);
    for(i=1; i<num; i++)
        printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to tell the OP where the bug was and why you only fixed that one bug, and not the others.

Answer (score 0):

### Program :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int num;
    //%d means you want to read an integer value where as %c is used for reading a character
    scanf("%d",&num);
    //Remove the semicolon after for loop
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
        printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

### Output :

```
$ gcc loop.c && ./a.out
4
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

Comment: In your code, you silently changed `1<num` to `i<num`. You may want to mention somewhere in your answer that you did this.